# Loop construction with multiple expressions for solving differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I want to solve the following ODE.

$H'' + \frac{2}{r}H'-\frac{\partial V_{eff}(H,r)}{\partial H}=0$

with the following conditions

$\frac{dH}{dr}(r=0)=0$ and $H(r= \infty)=0$

Regardless of the form of the potential $V_{eff}$ the above can't be solved analytically, so I have to perform it numerically.

In my case, the form of the $V_{eff}(H,r)$ and its derivative gets even worse.

I tried to solve it using `NDSolve`, but when I tried to set the boundary condition to infinity, the thing went to hell. (I saw another post here talking about the Airy equation which had a similar condition and the answer was to use the `ParametricNDSolve`, but for some reason, in my case, it doesn't work, probably due to the form of the potential and its derivative. If you have any suggestions on that issue, please let me know.)

So, I changed this condition and altered the problem from a Boundary Valued Problem to an Initial Condition one.

I asked another question on that matter where I tried to solve it by changing the condition $\frac{dH}{dr}(r=0)=0$ and instead used $H(r=0)=0.4$.

A lot of people responded and their replies were great, but the thing is that the form of the solution is not the desired one.

So, I was thinking of solving it in the following way in order to get a nice solution describing what I need.

What I want to do is break the above into a simpler problem, and create a loop that will calculate the ODE.

Mathematically, what I want to do is

$\qquad dH = \frac{dH}{dr}$

and then put the following expressions in a loop

$\qquad H(r+ε) = H(r) + εdH(r)$

$\qquad dH(r+ε)=dH(r)+ε \left (-\frac{2}{r}dH(r)+ \frac{\partial V_{eff}}{\partial H} \right)$

$\qquad r=r + ε$

and here the loop ends.

In the above, the ε is a small parameter which comes from the definition of derivatives as a limit.

My problem:

I have not found any examples of loops that will allow me to begin a loop with a command, end it with another command, put the above-mentioned code in the loop and when the procedure is done print the result. That is, have the same loop to calculate two expressions not just one.

Then, if possible, I would like to print the solution, $H(r)$. Otherwise, I can just look when the result converges and determine whether or not satisfies my criteria.

Any suggestion or help would be invaluable.

P.S1: This is the effective potential

```
V_{eff} = 3 (-4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + x] (x Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])^(
     3/2) (1 + 0.264464/(
       x Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])) - ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + x] + 
       HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + x]) (-0.00003904 + 
       0.0000359454 x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))]))/(
    0.0005219 - 0.00133643 x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))] + (
     0.00502655 x^2)/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))) + 
    1/2 (-HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + x] + 
       HeavisideTheta[x]) (-0.0000219325 - 
       0.00189062 x^3 (1/(1 - Log[x]/100))^(3/2) + (0.000418879 x^2)/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)) - (
       x^4 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 x^2)/(1 - Log[x]/100)]))/(
       1250 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^2))) + (
 4 π x^4 (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))) + (
    Sqrt[39] Tan[
      1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))])])/(
    500 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))))/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^2
```

and its derivative

```
3 (-4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])
      DiracDelta[-4.5 + x] (x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])^(
     3/2) (1 + 0.264464/(x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])) - 
    4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + x] (x Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])^(
     3/2) (-(0.264464/(x^2 Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])) - (
       0.00252544 Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])/x^2) - 
    4.23777*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + x] (x Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])^(
     3/2) (1 + 0.264464/(
       x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])) (-7.08982 Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))] - 
       0.0677028 (1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))^(3/2)) - 
    6.35666*10^-7 E^(-7.08982 x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])
      HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + x] Sqrt[
     x Sqrt[1/(
      1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))]] (1 + 0.264464/(
       x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))])) (Sqrt[1/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))] + (
       3 (1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))^(3/2))/(
       100 π)) + ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + x] + 
       HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + x]) (-0.00003904 + 
       0.0000359454 x Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))]) (-0.00133643 Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))] - 
       0.000012762 (1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))^(3/2) + (
       0.000096 x)/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^2 + (0.0100531 x)/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))))/(0.0005219 - 
      0.00133643 x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))] + (
      0.00502655 x^2)/(
      1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))^2 - ((-DiracDelta[-4.5 + x] + 
       DiracDelta[-1.8 + x]) (-0.00003904 + 
       0.0000359454 x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))]))/(
    0.0005219 - 0.00133643 x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))] + (
     0.00502655 x^2)/(
     1 - (3 Log[x])/(
      50 π))) - ((-HeavisideTheta[-4.5 + x] + 
       HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + x]) (0.0000359454 Sqrt[1/(
        1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))] + 
       3.43253*10^-7 (1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))^(3/2)))/(
    0.0005219 - 0.00133643 x Sqrt[1/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))] + (
     0.00502655 x^2)/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))) + 
    1/2 (-HeavisideTheta[-1.8 + x] + 
       HeavisideTheta[x]) (-0.00567185 x^2 (1/(1 - Log[x]/100))^(
        3/2) - 0.0000283593 x^2 (1/(1 - Log[x]/100))^(5/2) + (
       8.*10^-6 x)/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^2 - (
       0.0000159155 x^2 ((0.502655 x)/(1 - Log[x]/100)^2 + (
          100.531 x)/(1 - Log[x]/100)) (1 - Log[x]/100))/(1 - (
         3 Log[x])/(50 π))^2 + (0.000837758 x)/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)) - (
       3 x^3 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 x^2)/(1 - Log[x]/100)]))/(
       31250 π (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^3) - (
       2 x^3 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 x^2)/(1 - Log[x]/100)]))/(
       625 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^2)) + 
    1/2 (-DiracDelta[-1.8 + x] + DiracDelta[x]) (-0.0000219325 - 
       0.00189062 x^3 (1/(1 - Log[x]/100))^(3/2) + (0.000418879 x^2)/(
       1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)) - (
       x^4 (-5.41 + Log[(50.2655 x^2)/(1 - Log[x]/100)]))/(
       1250 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^2))) + (
 4 π x^4 (27/(25000 π x (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^2) + (
    39 Sec[1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))])]^2)/(
    50000 π x (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^2) + (
    3 Sqrt[39]
      Tan[1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))])])/(
    25000 π x (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^2)))/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(
   50 π))^2 + (
 12 x^3 (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))) + (
    Sqrt[39] Tan[
      1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))])])/(
    500 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))))/(
 25 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^3) + (
 16 π x^3 (9/(500 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))) + (
    Sqrt[39] Tan[
      1/2 Sqrt[13/
       3] (3.67407 + Log[1/(100 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))])])/(
    500 (1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π)))))/(1 - (3 Log[x])/(50 π))^2
```

Edit: The following does not reply the problem fully, but rather partially, however it is simpler case in the sense of the form of the potential (simple harmonic oscillator) and the loop-construction I was talking about looks like this

```
\[Epsilon] = 0.05; x = 0; f = 0; g = 1; i = 0;
Do[
 f1 = f + \[Epsilon]*g;
 g1 = g - \[Epsilon]*f;
 x1 = x + \[Epsilon]; i1 = i + 1;
 Print[x1, " ", f1, " ", g1];
 x = x1; f = f1; g = g1; i = i1,
 {i, 0, 100}]
```

So, having this as an example I hope that others will find it useful in solving similar D.E using this simple numeric updating procedure.

Comment: Various looping constructs include: Do, Table, Nest, NestList, NestWhile, NestWhileList, Fold, and FoldList.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am aware of those. 

What I meant was something more like 

BeginLoop
code that manipulates
EndLoop

just like what happens in C for example

Comment: I think you might have been too hasty in abandoning `NDSolve`, but you will to add the definition of the potential function to your question for us to be able to investigate what happens with `NDSolve`.

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you for your reply. 

the truth is that I might have done the mistake you mentioned. Abandoned the NDSolve too easily. I tried as hard as I could though. 

I included the for of the effective potential to my original post. 

P.S: huge fan of Goldberg as well

Comment: The `V[eff]` you post is a function of one variable, not two. How does it relate to the $V_{eff}$ in your ODE?

Comment: Fair point. Let me explain. 

I just wrote the most general case when explaining in the original post. The effective potential could in general be a function of the field and the distance (H and r respectively). 

I my case, it only depends on the field (H) which is written as x in the code.

Comment: Are there any limits on `H`?  For instance, do you require that `H > 0`?

Comment: Hi @bbgodfrey, no I do not require that H is positive. In fact it should take negative values to spontaneously break the symmetry.

Comment: In that case, is a numerical solution involving complex numbers acceptable?  There appears to be an essential singularity in `V` at `H == 0`, and I am uncertain whether any of the branches for `H < 0` are purely real.  By the way, it is easy to obtain two answers that go asymptotically to constants at infinite `r`, but neither constant is zero.

Comment: @bbgodfrey to begin with thank you for your time. 
I am only interested in the positive branch H>0 and I would like it go asymptotically to zero at infinity, or after a certain point. 
Otherwise, it would fail to obey the physical demands we need (it would not give a bubble).

Comment: I do not understand the combination of your last two comments.  The first states that `H` should take on negative values, and the second states that the `H > 0` is desired. In any case, I am troubled by negative `H`, because `V` is complex there.  Consequently, once `H < 0`, it will be complex as `r` approaches infinity, and the `DiracDelta[]` arguments can never be satisfied, even if the imaginary part of `H` is infinitesimal.  More generally, what does a complex potential mean?  Please clarify.  Thanks..

Comment: Although more information would be useful, I believe that the question can be answered with the information available.  Therefore, I recommend that it be reopened.

Comment: Sorry, it takes long to answer, but I am studying many things at the same time. 

Mathematically, a complex potential may be consistent and in Advanced Quantum Field Theory it can also be physically consistent. It has been argued in papers that even non-Hermitian Hamiltonians can give a positive spectrum and be phenomenologically viable. This is how the phi-cubed theory is no longer a toy model. 

Maybe I was not clear enough, but what I meant is that regardless of the negative part of it and if it is consistent I want/need to study the positive branch of it.

Comment: And I don't understand what they mean by additional information. I gave differential equation and the mathematical manipulation that leads to loop-construction and I explained the loop I need to construct and the help I needed there. The potential is included in the original post after a kind proposal. Maybe, someone could tell me what more I should had included for future references. Thank you in advance.